# Compressing pdfs

Tags: pdf, compression, ghostscript

I've been using a web service at ilovepdf.com to compress some PDF files. And by some, I mean "several hundred to several thousand". The output files look identical (to my eye) and weigh in at 95% of the original file size on down to 50% every 20th or 30th. I was happy with the output, but the transit time (uploading the original, dowloading the compressed) is significant. It's taking 1-3 minutes per file. Additionally, I'm not exactly a paying customer, and recently I've been throttled to to the point that it's 10-20 minutes per file.

I try not to be a moocher, and I had been expecting to switch to some local solution at some point anyway.

I got around to doing research (on and off for the past several years I've been checking out various solutions, never finding a better one... past several years, without my bulk compression) and I discovered that ilovepdf.com uses a library/framework developed by another company whose website is pdf-tools.com.

They offer a command-line version, which I've downloaded and experimented with. With the correct settings, I'm seeing similar size reduction and output. However, they do not even list prices on their website and instead have a "request quote" button. I think I'm priced out of this before I've even started. But, in the meantime I've discovered at least some of what ilovepdf.com must be doing.

```
pdfoptimize -v -se -or -od -oc -s -m -cff -sm -fc 8 -q 60 -lk [trial license key] input.pdf output.pdf
```

The breakdown of their options seems to be the following:

- -or : Remove redundant objects
- -od : Optimize resources
- -oc : Clip images (to the portion displayed in the pdf, apparently, some sort of cropping)
- -s : Subset embedded font programs
- -m : Merge embedded font progams
- -sm : Strip metadata (this is probably covered by -se as well)
- -fc : Compression types for continuous (color and monochrome); 8 = JPEG2000 compression
- -q : Quality, as per typical jpeg quality... and I don't need to set it so low as 60 to get decent reduction

Some of these options, upon further testing (-cff and -se) don't seem to be decreasing filesize at all, so I've edited them out of the list.

How many of these operations can be accomplished with open source tools, particularly ghostscript? I wouldn't need identical output (I understand enough about the pdf file format to know that's improbable), merely similarly reduced output.

Comment: Most such products just degrade the quality of the images. It looks similar enough to the naked eye, so you'll find out the magnitude of the disaster only when you try to print or use on a large HiRes monitor. My advice: Avoid these products, you're just destroying your files.

Comment: @harrymc These are not going to be printed. I collect newspapers, the so-called "e-papers" that are digital replicas of the print. Never going to print them off. My aim is to collect the 300 or 400 US daily newspapers (maybe some foreign too). The 10% file size reduction amounts to significantly less required capacity. I won't ever need to be able to see Steven Bannon's nosehair in the April 2017 edition of USA Today on page 3.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [HexaPDF command line tool](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/documentation/reference/hexapdf.1.html#optimize). However, it only does lossless PDF compression, so images won't be touched or reduced in size.

If you are wondering about its performance, have a look at the [optimization benchmarks](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/documentation/benchmarks/optimization.html).

It also has a batch mode to apply the optimization to multiple files in one go.